# changing paths for pip

Tags: python, configuration, pip, hidden-files

I have some problems with pip, and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101300/pip-could-not-find-any-downloads-that-satisfy-the-requirement-sqlalchemy):

it is suggested to change a line in any of these files:

```
 ~/.pypirc or $PIP_INDEX_URL or pip.conf
```

Problem is, I can't find any of these files. Where are they located? If they are hidden, how can I make them appear with command line only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easiest to use the local configuration file `~/.pypirc` as the other two options call for a little added complexity:

1. Definition of an environmental variable (`$PIP_INDEX_URL`)
2. Editing of another, more deeply nested, local file (`~/.config/pip/pip.conf`). This file might also be located in `/etc/pip/pip.conf` and in that location must be edited with the use of `sudo`.

The configuration file `~/.pypirc`, which is a *local* or *user* configuration file, is not necessarily always present but can be *created* with the following command:

```
touch ~/.pypirc
```

To show this file from the command line the conventional command is:

```
ls -la $HOME
```

The `-a` option, or `--all` in its long form, reveals the hidden files. Then you can go on to edit the file as you see fit from either command line or gui...

**References:**

- [6.2.4. The .pypirc file](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html?highlight=pypirc#pypirc)
- [Pip User Guide: pip.conf](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#config-file)

Comment: `touch ~/.pypirc` and then what? would be useful if you added the line that would change the path